# QGIS crashes when using "Split with lines" tool

Tags: qgis, line, qgis-processing, splitting, vector-layer

I want to use the ["Split with line"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoroverlay.html#split-with-lines) tool on a dataset with 5000 line features. It works if I select some of the lines, but on the whole dataset, it crashes.

Is there a way to solve/work around this issue in QGIS 3.26.3?

Comment: Have you ensured your line layer has valid geometry?

Comment: Application crashes are more a support than GIS SE issue. It should certainly be reported to the developers.

Comment: There are split with line tools in the SAGA and Whitebox (if you added it) sections of Processing that you might try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run [Geometry Checker](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/de/docs/user_manual/plugins/core_plugins/plugins_geometry_checker.html) to see if the lines are valid.

As an alternative, [explode](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/de/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#explode-lines) the line, [delete duplicate geometries](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/de/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#delete-duplicate-geometries), then select all lines and [merge](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/de/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#merge-vector-layers) selected features. Finally, run [Multipart to Single parts](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/de/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#multipart-to-singleparts). Then again try to split with lines.

Comment: The geometry check made it, thank you! I resolved some duplicate geometrys and duplicate nodes and afterwards it worked.