# QGIS (3.28.2) split features doesn't work

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, splitting

I have a QGIS-project with a set of features. I need to split these features into smaller ones. I use the 'Split features' tool and everything seems to work. The only problem is the feature is not split. The attribute table also shows no new feature (40 rows before and after split). I'm a bit puzzled as i have never run into this problem before.

When i make a new feature in this project and try to split it, it does that the way its supposed to do. Another oddity is that when i set a background color to my features and i select them, they don't go transparent as they should do when i select a feature. I get them selected, they just dont go transparent.

See the added picture for workflow. I also added a picture of the first two cols of the attribute table, just in case.
[image]

Hope someone recognizes this problem.

Comment: Are your polygons valid or do they contain geometry errors? Create a (very small) buffer around them and try again. Do you have multipart polygons? See also https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/445114/88814 and https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/402990/88814